# submit value with JavaScript instead html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

at the moment I'm using submit input type inside html. But it cause every time a reload of the whole page, when I hit the button. So because of it, I want to use JavaScript now, so my page doesnt reload every time. My problem: I dont know how, and hope someone will help. It's also possible to use jQuery?
This is my actual html button:

```
<html>
    <body>   
        <table class="buttons">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form method="post">
                        <p> <input name='"Variable".startstop' type="hidden"> </p>
                        <p> <input class="Start"value="Start" type="submit"> </p>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post">
                        <p> <input name='"Variable".startstop'value="0" type="hidden"> </p>
                        <p> <input class="Stop" value="Stop" type="submit"> </p>
                    </form>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

"Variable.startstop" is inside my plc and I would like to chage it from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1

Comment: You might want to start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or here for JQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

add id to your form and catch submit

```
<form id="target">

$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
      console.log( "Handler for .submit() called." );
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be specific AJAX is the solution to it, we can also use Fetch API for that. I would recommend using fetch. Before that change, your `type="Submit"` to `"type=button"`.

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Here put all your data of the form 
  const data = {};
  // Here is the call to your endpoint
  fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here is the response form the server
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error if any
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
})
```